# Passing Credentials using DSC and ARM Template and Deploying with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager, dsc

I am taking my first crack at making a DSC (Desired State Configuration) file to go with an ARM (Azure Resource Manager) template to deploy a Windows Server 2016 and so far everything was working great until I tried to pass a username/password so I can create a local Windows user account. I can't seem to make this function at all (see the error message below).

My question is, how do I use an ARM template to pull a password from an Azure key vault and pass it to a DSC powershell extension?

Here is my current setup:

### azuredeploy.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "deployExecUsername": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "DeployExec"
    },
    "deployExecPassword": {
      "type": "securestring"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated container in staging storage account to receive post-build staging folder upload"
      }
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken": {
      "type": "securestring",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Auto-generated token to access _artifactsLocation"
      }
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "web-app-server"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "CreateLocalUserArchiveFolder": "DSC",
    "CreateLocalUserArchiveFileName": "CreateLocalUser.zip"},
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/', 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "location": "eastus2",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "dependsOn": [ ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "CreateLocalUser"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "configuration": {
            "url": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), '/', variables('CreateLocalUserArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('CreateLocalUserArchiveFileName'))]",
            "script": "CreateLocalUser.ps1",
            "function": "Main"
          },
          "configurationArguments": {
            "nodeName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]"
          }
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "configurationArguments": {
            "deployExecCredential": {
              "UserName": "[parameters('deployExecUsername')]",
              "Password": "[parameters('deployExecPassword')]"
            }
          },
          "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken')]"
        }
      }
    }],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

### azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "deployExecPassword": {
      "reference": {
        "keyVault": {
          "id": "/subscriptions/<GUID>/resourceGroups/<Resource Group Name>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<Resource Group Name>-key-vault"
        },
        "secretName": "web-app-server-deployexec-password"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### DSC/CreateLocalUser.ps1

```
Configuration Main
{
    Param ( 
        [string] $nodeName,
        [PSCredential]$deployExecCredential 
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration

    Node $nodeName
    {
        User DeployExec
        {
            Ensure = "Present"
            Description = "Deployment account for Web Deploy"
            UserName = $deployExecCredential.UserName
            Password = $deployExecCredential
            PasswordNeverExpires = $true
            PasswordChangeRequired = $false
            PasswordChangeNotAllowed = $true
        }
    }
}
```

### Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1 (Default from Azure Resource Group template)

```
#Requires -Version 3.0

Param(
    [string] [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] $ResourceGroupLocation,
    [string] $ResourceGroupName = 'AzureResourceGroup2',
    [switch] $UploadArtifacts,
    [string] $StorageAccountName,
    [string] $StorageContainerName = $ResourceGroupName.ToLowerInvariant() + '-stageartifacts',
    [string] $TemplateFile = 'azuredeploy.json',
    [string] $TemplateParametersFile = 'azuredeploy.parameters.json',
    [string] $ArtifactStagingDirectory = '.',
    [string] $DSCSourceFolder = 'DSC',
    [switch] $ValidateOnly
)

try {
    [Microsoft.Azure.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::ClientFactory.AddUserAgent("VSAzureTools-$UI$($host.name)".replace(' ','_'), '3.0.0')
} catch { }

$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
Set-StrictMode -Version 3

function Format-ValidationOutput {
    param ($ValidationOutput, [int] $Depth = 0)
    Set-StrictMode -Off
    return @($ValidationOutput | Where-Object { $_ -ne $null } | ForEach-Object { @('  ' * $Depth + ': ' + $_.Message) + @(Format-ValidationOutput @($_.Details) ($Depth + 1)) })
}

$OptionalParameters = New-Object -TypeName Hashtable
$TemplateFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $TemplateFile))
$TemplateParametersFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $TemplateParametersFile))

if ($UploadArtifacts) {
    # Convert relative paths to absolute paths if needed
    $ArtifactStagingDirectory = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $ArtifactStagingDirectory))
    $DSCSourceFolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath([System.IO.Path]::Combine($PSScriptRoot, $DSCSourceFolder))

    # Parse the parameter file and update the values of artifacts location and artifacts location SAS token if they are present
    $JsonParameters = Get-Content $TemplateParametersFile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    if (($JsonParameters | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty 'parameters') -ne $null) {
        $JsonParameters = $JsonParameters.parameters
    }
    $ArtifactsLocationName = '_artifactsLocation'
    $ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName = '_artifactsLocationSasToken'
    $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationName] = $JsonParameters | Select -Expand $ArtifactsLocationName -ErrorAction Ignore | Select -Expand 'value' -ErrorAction Ignore
    $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName] = $JsonParameters | Select -Expand $ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName -ErrorAction Ignore | Select -Expand 'value' -ErrorAction Ignore

    # Create DSC configuration archive
    if (Test-Path $DSCSourceFolder) {
        $DSCSourceFilePaths = @(Get-ChildItem $DSCSourceFolder -File -Filter '*.ps1' | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName})
        foreach ($DSCSourceFilePath in $DSCSourceFilePaths) {
            $DSCArchiveFilePath = $DSCSourceFilePath.Substring(0, $DSCSourceFilePath.Length - 4) + '.zip'
            Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration $DSCSourceFilePath -OutputArchivePath $DSCArchiveFilePath -Force -Verbose
        }
    }

    # Create a storage account name if none was provided
    if ($StorageAccountName -eq '') {
        $StorageAccountName = 'stage' + ((Get-AzureRmContext).Subscription.SubscriptionId).Replace('-', '').substring(0, 19)
    }

    $StorageAccount = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccount | Where-Object{$_.StorageAccountName -eq $StorageAccountName})

    # Create the storage account if it doesn't already exist
    if ($StorageAccount -eq $null) {
        $StorageResourceGroupName = 'ARM_Deploy_Staging'
        New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Location "$ResourceGroupLocation" -Name $StorageResourceGroupName -Force
        $StorageAccount = New-AzureRmStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -Type 'Standard_LRS' -ResourceGroupName $StorageResourceGroupName -Location "$ResourceGroupLocation"
    }

    # Generate the value for artifacts location if it is not provided in the parameter file
    if ($OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationName] -eq $null) {
        $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationName] = $StorageAccount.Context.BlobEndPoint + $StorageContainerName
    }

    # Copy files from the local storage staging location to the storage account container
    New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccount.Context -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue *>&1

    $ArtifactFilePaths = Get-ChildItem $ArtifactStagingDirectory -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName}
    foreach ($SourcePath in $ArtifactFilePaths) {
        Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $SourcePath -Blob $SourcePath.Substring($ArtifactStagingDirectory.length + 1) `
            -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Force
    }

    # Generate a 4 hour SAS token for the artifacts location if one was not provided in the parameters file
    if ($OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName] -eq $null) {
        $OptionalParameters[$ArtifactsLocationSasTokenName] = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force `
            (New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Container $StorageContainerName -Context $StorageAccount.Context -Permission r -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddHours(4))
    }
}

# Create or update the resource group using the specified template file and template parameters file
New-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -Location $ResourceGroupLocation -Verbose -Force

if ($ValidateOnly) {
    $ErrorMessages = Format-ValidationOutput (Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                                                                  -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                                                                  -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                                                                  @OptionalParameters)
    if ($ErrorMessages) {
        Write-Output '', 'Validation returned the following errors:', @($ErrorMessages), '', 'Template is invalid.'
    }
    else {
        Write-Output '', 'Template is valid.'
    }
}
else {
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $TemplateFile).BaseName + '-' + ((Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()).ToString('MMdd-HHmm')) `
                                       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                                       -TemplateFile $TemplateFile `
                                       -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParametersFile `
                                       @OptionalParameters `
                                       -Force -Verbose `
                                       -ErrorVariable ErrorMessages
    if ($ErrorMessages) {
        Write-Output '', 'Template deployment returned the following errors:', @(@($ErrorMessages) | ForEach-Object { $_.Exception.Message.TrimEnd("`r`n") })
    }
}
```

Do note that my original template deploys the entire server, but I am able to reproduce the issue I am having with the above template and any old Windows Server 2016 VM.

I am running the template through Visual Studio 2017 Community:

[image]

[image]

The template validates and runs, but when I run it I am getting the following error message:

```
22:26:41 - New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:26:41 PM - VM has reported a failure when processing extension 
22:26:41 - 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: "The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: Compilation errors occurred 
22:26:41 - while processing configuration 'Main'. Please review the errors reported in error stream and modify your configuration 
22:26:41 - code appropriately. System.InvalidOperationException error processing property 'Password' OF TYPE 'User': Converting 
22:26:41 - and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing credentials in MOF 
22:26:41 - file, please refer to MSDN blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729
22:26:41 - At C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\DSCWork\CreateLocalUser.4\CreateLocalUser.ps1:12 char:3
22:26:41 - +   User Converting and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing 
22:26:41 - credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729 Cannot find path 
22:26:41 - 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not exist. Cannot find path 
22:26:41 - 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not exist.
22:26:41 - Another common error is to specify parameters of type PSCredential without an explicit type. Please be sure to use a 
22:26:41 - typed parameter in DSC Configuration, for example:
22:26:41 -     configuration Example {
22:26:41 -         param([PSCredential] $UserAccount)
22:26:41 -         ...
22:26:41 -     }.
22:26:41 - Please correct the input and retry executing the extension.".
22:26:41 - At F:\Users\Shad\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\AzureResourceGroup2\AzureResourceGroup2\bin\Debug\staging\AzureR
22:26:41 - esourceGroup2\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1:108 char:5
22:26:41 - +     New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name ((Get-ChildItem $Templat ...
22:26:41 - +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
22:26:41 -     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
22:26:41 -     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep 
22:26:41 -    loymentCmdlet
```

## What I Tried

I have already tried looking at this question:

- [Passing credentials to DSC script from arm template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42514654)

but it seems to be using the old ARM template format to construct the DSC call and since I am not familiar with it, I am unable to work out what the extra parameters are for.

I also took a look at this question:

- [Securely pass credentials to DSC Extension from ARM Template](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43498772)

and the accepted answer is to just use `PsDSCAllowPlainTextPassword = $true`. While this doesn't seem like the best way, I tried adding the following configuration data file.

### CreateLocalUser.psd1

```
#
# CreateLocalUser.psd1
#
@{
    AllNodes = @(
        @{
            NodeName = '*'
            PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
        }
    )
}
```

And changing `Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1` to pass these settings to the DSC configuration, as follows.

```
# Create DSC configuration archive
if (Test-Path $DSCSourceFolder) {
    $DSCSourceFilePaths = @(Get-ChildItem $DSCSourceFolder -File -Filter '*.ps1' | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.FullName})
    foreach ($DSCSourceFilePath in $DSCSourceFilePaths) {
        $DSCArchiveFilePath = $DSCSourceFilePath.Substring(0, $DSCSourceFilePath.Length - 4) + '.zip'
        $DSCConfigDataFilePath = $DSCSourceFilePath.Substring(0, $DSCSourceFilePath.Length - 4) + '.psd1'
        Publish-AzureRmVMDscConfiguration $DSCSourceFilePath -OutputArchivePath $DSCArchiveFilePath -ConfigurationDataPath $DSCConfigDataFilePath -Force -Verbose
    }
}
```

However, I am not getting any change in the error message when doing so.

I have been through loads of the Azure documentation to try to work this out. The link in the error message is entirely unhelpful as there are no examples of how to use the encryption with an ARM template. Most of the examples are showing running Powershell scripts rather than an ARM template. And there isn't a single example in the documentation anywhere on how to retrieve the password from a key vault and pass it into a DSC extension file from an ARM template. Is this even possible?

> Note that I would be happy with simply using Visual Studio to do my deployment, if I could just get it working. But I have been working on this issue for several days and cannot seem to find a single solution that works. So, I thought I would ask here before throwing in the towel and just using the admin Windows account for web deployment.

### UPDATE 2018-12-21

I noticed when running the deploy command through Visual Studio 2017 that the log contains an error message:

```
20:13:43 - Build started.
20:13:43 - Project "web-app-server.deployproj" (StageArtifacts target(s)):
20:13:43 - Project "web-app-server.deployproj" (ContentFilesProjectOutputGroup target(s)):
20:13:43 - Done building project "web-app-server.deployproj".
20:13:43 - Done building project "web-app-server.deployproj".
20:13:43 - Build succeeded.
20:13:43 - Launching PowerShell script with the following command:
20:13:43 - 'F:\Projects\thepath\web-app-server\bin\Debug\staging\web-app-server\Deploy-AzureResourceGroup.ps1' -StorageAccountName 'staged<xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx>' -ResourceGroupName 'web-app-server' -ResourceGroupLocation 'eastus2' -TemplateFile 'F:\Projects\thepath\web-app-server\bin\Debug\staging\web-app-server\web-app-server.json' -TemplateParametersFile 'F:\Projects\thepath\web-app-server\bin\Debug\staging\web-app-server\web-app-server.parameters.json' -ArtifactStagingDirectory '.' -DSCSourceFolder '.\DSC' -UploadArtifacts
20:13:43 - Deploying template using PowerShell script failed.
20:13:43 - Tell us about your experience at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691202
```

After the error message occurs, it continues. I suspect it may be falling back to using another method and it is that method that is causing the failure and why others are not seeing what I am.

Comment: why do you ask about pulling credentials from key vault when your template doesnt work as it? can you tell me which question you want answered? :)

Comment: The first one. How can the credentials be passed into the DSC when using an ARM template? The proposed solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43498772) don't work at all. And other solutions are using older ARM syntax which I would prefer not to use, if possible.

Comment: tbh, I dont see much difference with what you are using and what I'm using, consider changing you variable type in DSC configuration to what I'm using. oh I just noticed you are using KV in the param file. that should work, it looks fine

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, no matter what I try this does not function with DSC.

### Workaround

For now, I am working around this issue using a custom script extension, like this:

```
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/addWindowsAccounts')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": []
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
          "commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command \"& { $secureDeployExecPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String ', variables('quote'), parameters('deployExecPassword'), variables('quote'), ' -AsPlainText -Force; New-LocalUser -AccountNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword -Name ', variables('quote'), parameters('deployExecUsername'), variables('quote'), ' -Password $secureDeployExecPassword -FullName ', variables('quote'), parameters('deployExecUsername'), variables('quote'), ' -Description ', variables('quote'), 'Deployment account for Web Deploy', variables('quote'), ' -ErrorAction Continue ', '}\"')]"
        }
      }
    }
```

And then [using dependsOn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45753135) to force the custom script extension to run before DSC by setting these on the DSC extension.

```
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]",
        "addWindowsAccounts"
      ],
```

Not the ideal solution, but it is secure and gets me past this blocking issue without resorting to using the administrator password for website deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of the recent ones I'm using:

Configuration:

```
Param(
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
)
```

and in the template I do this:

```
"publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
"type": "DSC",
"typeHandlerVersion": "2.20",
"autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
"settings": {
    "configuration": {
        "url": "url.zip",
        "script": "file.ps1",
        "function": "configuration"
    }
},
"protectedSettings": {
    "configurationArguments": {
        "adminCreds": {
            "userName": "username",
            "password": "password"
        }
    }
}
```

You dont need `PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword` because they are auto encrypted by powershell.dsc extension.

Comment: I tried adding the namespace `System.Management.Automation` as well as changing the `typeHandlerVersion` to `2.20`, to no effect. I also tried hard-coding the username and password (and even changed the password to one without symbols in it) to no effect. Are you deploying this through Visual Studio? Did you try the example that I posted to see if you can get it working?

Comment: I am starting to wonder if this has something to do with the fact that my server name has dashes or some other naming that I am using that DSC is choking on. Whatever the case, I am still getting the same error `System.InvalidOperationException error processing property 'Password' OF TYPE 'User': Converting and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended.`

Comment: i'm deploying with custom powershell. I could try your template, sure. just give me a couple of hours. I just got up :) meanwhile, can you try removing: `Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration` (its not needed) and removing $nodename parameter and chainging: `Node $nodeName` to `Node localhost`? in your dsc and rerun it?